# Testing for null in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In AS3, I would often do something like this

```
if(myObject != null)
{
  //if we get here then myObject is ready to go

}
else
{
  //myObject = null so we need to set it up
}
```

In Obj-c I understand you initialise an object like this...

```
myObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

But how would I do a similar check in obj-c, as I would do in AS3, and/or is that the best way to do that? should there be another way to know if an object has already been initialised and if it hasn't set up?

So when I'm done with the object in AS3, I just need to do

```
myObject = null;
```

And the code knows to set it up next time it comes to that conditional code.

Comment: test against `nil` or `NULL` - but wasn't this in the Objective-C tutorial that you **do have read?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it the same way. The null pointer in Objective-C is `nil`.

```
if (myObject != nil) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else 
}
```

Objective-C can also treat any object as a boolean (if the object is `nil` (0), the boolean will be false), so you can leave out `nil` too:

```
if (myObject) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else 
}
```

Comment: "casting to a boolean" is not entirely precise, no cast occurs in the 2nd case, it's only that nonzero numerical values will be treated as true.

Comment: Minor nitpick - In your 2nd bit of code, that isn't casting. In C, any value of 0 is treated as false, and non-zero value is treat as true. So a nil object reference is 0 so it's treated as false. No casting is done.

Comment: I'm using ARC, does that complicate matters any with setting an object to nil?

Comment: @DrummerB I guess `C treats all nonzero numerical values as a true condition' would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nil` in Objective-C.

```
if (myObject != nil) {
}
```

or even easier:

```
if (myObject) {
}
```